# How can I make an arbitrary UIAccessibilityElement behave like a UISwitch for VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiswitch, voiceover

When selecting a native switch with VoiceOver, the announcement will contain "Off" or "On" with an additional hint "double tap to toggle setting".

I have tried using the accessibility trait `UIAccessibilityTraitSelected`, but that only results in "Selected" being announced, with no hint unless I provide one explicitly.

Using the Accessibility Inspector I've also noticed that native UIKit switches have an accessibilityValue of `1` when enabled, but providing that does not change VoiceOver behavior.

```
- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits {
  if (toggled) {
    return UIAccessibilityTraitSelected;
  } else {
    return UIAccessibilityTraitNone;
  }
}

- (NSString*)accessibilityValue {
  if (toggled) {
    return @"1";
  } else {
    return @"0"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to provide some combination of traits/value/label such that TalkBack recognizes this element as a Switch, without using a UISwitch?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have created an accessible view that acts like a switch [here](https://github.com/jldailey13/24-Accessibility-Article-Examples/blob/master/24A11y%20Article/Name%20Examples/AccessibleSwitchView.swift).

The only way that I have been able to get any arbitrary element to act like a Switch is when inheriting the UIAccessibilityTraits of a Switch.  This causes VoiceOver to read the Accessibility Value (`0` or `1`) as "Off" or "On," adds the hint "Double tap to toggle setting", and makes VoiceOver say "Switch Button."

You could potentially do this by overriding the view's Accessibility Traits like so:

```
override var accessibilityTraits(): UIAccessibilityTraits {
    get { return UISwitch().accessibilityTraits }
    set {}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could achieve similar behavior without creating the empty switch object, by subclassing UISwitch.

Comment: UISwitch().accessibilityTraits returns [.none] on iOS 16, how is this helpful?

Comment: iOS has access to private traits that don't belong to the traditional "accessibilityTraits" list, but that influence the way controls are announced. Controls that report that they have no traits only include the ones available in the traits enum, NOT traits that are private and belong to the bitmask. 

This technique allows you to pull in "private traits" without caring about what they are or getting kicked out of the App store.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom accessibility element behaving like a UISwitchControl with whatever you want.
The only thing to be specified is the way VoiceOver should interpret it.

Let's suppose you want to gather a `label` and a `view` to be seen as a switch control.

First of all, **create a class for grouping these elements** into a single one :

```
class WrapView: UIView {

static let defaultValue = "on"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


convenience init(with label: UILabel,and view: UIView) {

    let viewFrame = label.frame.union(view.frame)
    self.init(frame: viewFrame)

    self.isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.accessibilityLabel = label.accessibilityLabel
    self.accessibilityValue = WrapView.defaultValue
    self.accessibilityHint = "element is" + self.accessibilityValue! + ", tap twice to change the status."
}
}
```

Then, just **create your custom view** in your `viewDidAppear()` :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let myCustomView = WrapView.init(with: myLabel, and: myView)

    self.view.addSubview(myCustomView)
}
}
```

Finally, to have a custom view behaving like a switch control, just override the `accessibilityActivate` function in your `WrapView` class to implement your logic when your view is double tapped :

```
override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {

    self.accessibilityValue = (self.accessibilityValue == WrapView.defaultValue) ? "off" : "on"
    self.accessibilityHint = "element is" + self.accessibilityValue! + ", tap twice to change the status."

    return true
}
```

And now you have a custom element that contains whatever you want and that behaves like a switch control for blind people using VoiceOver without using a UISwitch as you wanted.

Comment: The answer below is much better. This answer is fragile and doesn't capture all of the behaviors of a UISwitch. Just the ones that are obvious.

Comment: You're right @ChrisCM, it's definitely much better because it encompasses many behaviors.  The code I provided had the humble purpose to show how to deal with a simple and specific example in order to understand the basics: when assimilated, the next step is the jldailey's for sure, I agree. 

Comment: Very nice response XLE_22. I get nervious when accepted answers are not as good as others. Folks that readily point out the value of someone else's answer are awesome!